# How can we generate sequence diagram in IntelliJ IDEA from Java code which is editable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml, reverse-engineering, sequence-diagram

I am currently using SequenceDiagram Plugin from  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286?pr= to generate Sequence Diagrams.
But here the drawback is that I am not able to save them in a format like .uml or any other format so anyone can open this file and edit it.
It only allows to export the sequnce diagram as an image.

Is there any way to save the sequence diagrams generated so they can be edited later?

Answer (score 7):

As the file https://github.com/Vanco/SequencePlugin/blob/master/src/org/intellij/sequencer/diagram/app/actions/ExportAction.java shows the plugin is able to export into images only. According to the [licence](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vanco/SequencePlugin/master/LICENSE) you can modify the software if you keep in mind [this part](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#redistribution) of the licence.

I think it is a good feature you suggested, it is not an easy job tho. If you plan to extend the feature try to contact with https://github.com/Vanco. I think it would be a handy thing for all of us!

**Edit:**
I posted it as a comment, but it is part of the answer:

> Here is a github repo: https://github.com/sherif181/java-sequence-diagram-generator it is not a plugin but looks handy for your case. It will generate LaTex documents that could be edited.

Comment: Do you know any alternate way of generating editable sequence diagrams in IntelliJ?

Comment: I do not really know such plugin but you should take a look at this repo: https://github.com/sherif181/java-sequence-diagram-generator it is not a plugin but looks handy for your case.